Node.js not installed properly
After installation a pop up message appears just before the last step of installation  it is showing installation was interrupted enter image description here
I want to install node.js in my system but in the middle of installation it is showing enter image description here

did you cilck yes or no when second screenshot window popped up?

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you


Try to use uninstall software to proper uninstall the NodeJS first (Iobit Uninstaller).
Download the .msi or .exe file as per your system environment (32-bit &
64-bit).
Then download Microsoft visual sudio and install windows build tools and c++ form it
Then try to run .msi or .exe file and installed the nodejs

